# How to make HTTPS (not HTTP) request use akka-http?

Tags: akka, akka-http

I am using the following code to make HTTP request with `akka-http` library inside of Akka Actor:

```scala
implicit val materializer = ActorFlowMaterializer()
implicit val system = context.system

val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, "http://ya.ru")
val content = for {
  response <- Http().singleRequest(request)
  content <- Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String]
} yield content
```

All works fine, but now I want to make HTTPS request (just replace `http://` to `https://`). After that the `content` variable will contain the following response:

```
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Seems like `akka-http` doesn't support HTTPS protocol. Is it right or possible to send HTTPS request use `akka-http`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look on the [official documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/server-side-https-support.html), you can see that you have to configure the HTTPS context. Then it should work.

Comment: I was using old version of `akka-http` (RC2 instead of RC4) and artifactId (`akka-http-scala-experimental` instead of `akka-http-experimental`) in my `build.sbt`. Your answer helped me to get it.